# How to properly debug an ASP.NET MVC Core with Visual Studio Code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-mvc, vscode-debugger

I'm having difficulties debugging a MVC ASP.NET Core application with Visual Studio Code.

I'm opening the folder that contains the project I want to run in VS Code.

The relevant part of the .csproj file is the following:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>aspnet-XXXXXXX-941AF9EA-C0DF-419D-B0F8-69FE3A477A65</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)Builds\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <AddRazorSupportForMvc>true</AddRazorSupportForMvc>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Now the launch.json content is the following:

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to find out which attributes exist for C# debugging
  // Use hover for the description of the existing attributes
  // For further information visit https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger-launchjson.md
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "watch",
      // If you have changed target frameworks, make sure to update the program path.
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/Builds/Debug/XXXXXXX.dll",
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      // Enable launching a web browser when ASP.NET Core starts. For more information: https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-WebBrowser
      "serverReadyAction": {
        "action": "openExternally",
        "pattern": "\\bNow listening on:\\s+(https?://\\S+)"
      },
      "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Attach",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "request": "attach",
      "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, when I open a code file, set a breakpoint and choose to launch the app, the compilation takes place but the browser is not ran at the end...

More surprisingly, the output of the build goes to the terminal, not the debug console:

```
Executing task: dotnet watch run /Users/omatrot/Documents/bealink/bealink_server/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/XXXXXXX.csproj /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary <
```

Then I press CTRL+C to stop the hosting process...
VS Code then immediately runs it again, this time outputting in the debug console, opening the browser, and stopping on my breakpoints.

This seems crazy to me.

EDIT 1: This works under Visual Studio by removing the following reference:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.LibraryManager.Build" Version="2.1.113" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need read [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) first, and know we need add some extensions in vscode.

And you can [read Jason Watmore's blog](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/06/24/vs-code-net-debug-a-net-web-app-in-visual-studio-code), In the blog, how to debug is introduced in detail. You can create task.json and `launch.json`. There are also video tutorials for our reference.

Comment: I've done that already. I've probably not been very clear about this, but I'm working on a complex existing project, not a simple one where it always works.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT Can you check this blog, https://wakeupandcode.com/debugging-multiple-net-core-projects-in-vs-code/ .